# Scrollbar is flickering

Tags: bug, status-declined, chat, scrolling

When you go to a chat room and you scroll all the way to the bottom, the scrollbar keeps appearing, disappearing, appearing, and repeat.  Every time the scollbar appears, the site scrolls up about 1 pixel then down again.  It only happens *sometimes,* though.  I'm looking for a pattern to reproduce the problem.

I am on a Macbook pro with OS X Mavericks 10.9.1 with Chrome version 34.0.1843.2 canary.

[image: Proof]

^ Notice how the scrollbar keeps re-appearing.

Comment: Using what browser (+version)? Mobile or non-mobile version?

Comment: Cannot reproduce with firefox and chromium (Version 32.0.1700.107 (248368)).

Comment: @LaszloPapp Chrome version 34.0.1843.2 canary

Comment: Chrome Canary is not supported http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need

Comment: I thought it is a real bug on the screen... that little black dot..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We will not be supporting browsers that are in alpha/beta status.

Please report bugs with **current, release versions** of browsers.